# Overriding tokenizer of scikitlearn vectorizer with spacy

Tags: python, scikit-learn, spacy, tfidfvectorizer

I want to implement lemmatization with `Spacy` package.
Here is my code :

```
regexp = re.compile( '(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b' )
en_nlp = spacy.load('en')
old_tokenizer = en_nlp.tokenizer
en_nlp.tokenizer = lambda string: old_tokenizer.tokens_from_list(regexp.findall(string))

def custom_tokenizer(document):
    doc_spacy = en_nlp(document)
    return [token.lemma_ for token in doc_spacy]

lemma_tfidfvect = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer= custom_tokenizer,stop_words = 'english')
```

But this error message was occured when i run that code.

```
C:\Users\yu\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py:193: DeprecationWarning: Tokenizer.from_list is now deprecated. Create a new Doc object instead and pass in the strings as the `words` keyword argument, for example:
from spacy.tokens import Doc
doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=[...])
  "__main__", mod_spec)
```

How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

To customize spaCy's *tokenizer*, you need to pass it a list of dictionaries that specify the word that needs custom tokenization and the orths it should be split into. Here's the example code from the [docs](https://spacy.io/api/tokenizer#add_special_case):

```
from spacy.attrs import ORTH, LEMMA
case = [{"don't": [{ORTH: "do"}, {ORTH: "n't", LEMMA: "not"}]}]
tokenizer.add_special_case(case)
```

If you're doing this all because you're wanting to make a custom *lemmatizer*, you might be better off just creating a custom lemma list directly. You'd have to modify the language data of spaCy itself, but the format is pretty simple:

```
"dustiest": ("dusty",),
"earlier": ("early",),
"earliest": ("early",),
"earthier": ("earthy",),
...
```

Those files live [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/en/lemmatizer/) for English.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code runs fine, you are just getting a `DeprecationWarning`, which is not really an error.

Following the advice given by the warning, I think you can modify your code substituting

```
en_nlp.tokenizer = lambda string: Doc(en_nlp.vocab, words = regexp.findall(string))
```

and that should run fine with no warnings (it does today on my machine).